# Using Pointers in lieu of Arrays

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I am definitely new to the C game, and would love some help with the following code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int cases;
    scanf("%d", &cases);
    printf("%d", cases);

    int i;
    int *heights;
    for(i=0; i<cases; i++){
        scanf("%d", &heights[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that it segfaults because I'm giving `scanf` a `NULL` pointer, so is there any way to allow `scanf` to feed values into this pointer? Or is there  a better method to get a variable number of arguments from `stdin` which I'm missing entirely?

Comment: On a side note you are (probably) not giving anything a NULL pointer. Leaving variables unassigned means they have an undefined value so could be anything.

Comment: The main problem is heights is defined as a pointer and you have not (probably via malloc()) given it anything to point to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`malloc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) to dynamically allocate space for `heights`.

```
int *heights = malloc(cases*sizeof(int));
```

And `free` pointer by calling `free(heights)` when you are done with `heights`.

For small value of `cases` you can use [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array):

```
 int heights[cases];
```

and do not forget to compile your code in C99 mode (`-std=c99`).

Comment: +1 And make a habit of invoking `free()` for anything you `malloc()`.

Answer (score 3):

heights pointer does not contain any memory.so first you have to allocate the memory using malloc system call according to the requirement.
syntax for malloc in your case -

`heights = (int *)malloc(cases*sizeof(int));`

one thing to remember, after dynamic memeory location you have to free it.syntax for memory free -

`free(heights)`